# Cannot install revel framework form Go

Tags: go, revel

I tried to install [Revel Framework](https://revel.github.io/). I followed all the steps as given in the documentation but whenever I tried to run the Revel command it throws **panic** error.
Following are the steps which I am performing
Enviormental path:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=/Users/<username>/Desktop/gocode
export PATH="/Users/<username>/gocode/bin:$PATH"
```

To install Revel

```
go get github.com/revel/revel
go get github.com/revel/cmd/revel
export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
```

when I run revel version it shows:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/revel/cmd/model.(*CommandConfig).UpdateImportPath(0xc4200961c0, 0x20)
    /Users/amitsharma/Desktop/gocode/src/github.com/revel/cmd/model/command_config.go:122 +0x907
main.main()
    /Users/amitsharma/Desktop/gocode/src/github.com/revel/cmd/revel/revel.go:133 +0x243
```

When I run

```
revel run -a my-app
```

It shows

```
ERROR 19:34:59 harness.go:231: Could not start application              error="revel/harness: app died reason: exit status 2"
INFO  19:34:59 watcher.go:272: Watcher: Recording error last build, setting rebuild on error="App failed to start up: revel/harness: app died reason: exit status 2"
INFO  19:34:59 watcher.go:277: Rebuilt, result                          error="App failed to start up: revel/harness: app died reason: exit status 2"
```

My go version

```
go version go1.10.3 darwin/amd64
```

My go env

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/amitsharma/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/<username>/Desktop/gocode"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/0d/pkfrs5cj0v57xgsnwvb2kb580000gn/T/go-build028697826=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue with Revel at the moment: https://github.com/revel/cmd/issues/142, https://github.com/revel/revel/issues/1374

Comment: Now revel team has solved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-install the revel

Here is how I have tried and it works for me.

1. Set the go path ($GOPATH):

```
export GOPATH=/var/projects/go
```

2. Install revel & cmd:

```
  go get github.com/revel/revel
  go get github.com/revel/cmd/revel
```

3. Link revel cmd to bin directory. So the command could be executable.

```
export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

4. Check revel is working or not.  Just type `revel` in command line

**Output would be like this**

```
    Usage:
      revel [OPTIONS] <command>

    Application Options:
      -v, --debug              If set the logger is set to verbose
          --historic-run-mode  If set the runmode is passed a string not json
      -X, --build-flags=       These flags will be used when building the application. May be specified multiple times, only applicable for Build, Run,
                               Package, Test commands

    Available commands:
      build
      clean
      new
      package
      run
      test
      version
```

5. Check revel version:

```
revel version
```

**Output**

```
    Revel executing: displays the Revel Framework and Go version
    Revel Framework :   0.21.0  (0.21.0 remote master branch)
    Revel Cmd   :   0.21.1  (0.21.1 remote master branch)
    Revel Modules   :   0.21.0  (0.21.0 remote master branch)
```

6. Now, You can create first project using command

```
revel new myapp
```

**Output**

```
    Revel executing: create a skeleton Revel application
    Your application has been created in:
       /var/projects/go/src/myapp

    You can run it with:
    revel run -a  myapp
```

Comment: This issue solved by the framework creators, appreciates your effort.